# I can't figure out general formula for this series

Tags: php, math, mathematical-optimization, series

I've made php code to generate invoice pdf. First the items of all purchased products are printed (`required rows`), and then `filler rows` (**so that subtotal and total are always printed at the end of page**), at last, subtotal and total. After hours of thinking, I came up with following logic.

I'm using the logic to figure out additional "filler rows" which is calculated from 'required rows'.

Here, the digit `21` is the total number of rows, first page can contain. Rest pages can contain 27 rows.

```
if($required_rows < 21) 
    $filler_rows = 20 - $required_rows;

    // I want a general formula for below series, which I currently use statically like this. 
else  if($required_rows < 48)  // 21 + 27 = 48
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*0));
else if($required_rows < 75) { // 48 + 27 = 75
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*1));
} else if($required_rows < 102) { // 75 + 27 = 102
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*2));
} else if($required_rows < 129) { // 102 + 27 = 129
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*3));
} else if($required_rows < 156) { // 129 + 27 = 156
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*4));
} else if($required_rows < 183) { // 156 + 27 = 183
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*5));
} else if($required_rows < 210) { // 182 + 27 = 210
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*6));
} else if($required_rows < 237) { // 210 + 27 = 237
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*7));
} else if($required_rows < 264) { // 237 + 27 = 264
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*8));
} else if($required_rows < 291) { // 264 + 27 = 291
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*9));
} else if($required_rows < 318) { // 291 + 27 = 318
    $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*10));
}
... ... ...
... ... ...
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try using the `for` to the same logic?

Comment: I don't think `for` can help. as it is the matter of logic sequence, not an output sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you're looking for:

```
$filler_rows = 26 - ($required_rows - 21) % 27;
```

Comment: You simplify that logic like WTF. I still can't believe that preg_split that did everything in one line.

Comment: It was a compliment, @SohanPatel. Simplify is a great skill.

Answer (score 0):

Please try code below.

```
if($required_rows < 21) 
    $filler_rows = 20 - $required_rows;    
}else{
    $multiplier = ($required_rows -21)/27;
    if($multiplier>=0){
        $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*$multiplier));    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best use Paul Crovella's answer

```
$num = 21;
if($required_rows < 21) 
    $filler_rows = 20 - $required_rows;
else {
    $i = 0;
    while(true){
        $num = $num + 27;
        if($required_rows < $num) {
            $filler_rows = 24 - ($required_rows - 23 - (27*$i));
            break;
        } else {
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```